Hy there ! i am getting this erorr using next14.2.2 i am trying to provide the tanstack provider to my nex app
**My app code is here that i implement as a whole wrapper i provide everything but still getting the error **
import React from "react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient(); // Create an instance of QueryClient

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: any) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;


please add error as well what error you are getting

@KamleshPaul thank you for asking i resolved the issue i was trying to provide the tanstack provider to my next js app in the layout so i was getting unexpected error .. but i did it .
Thank you for time
